# What is the most elegant way to split data and produce seasonal boxplots?

Tags: r, date, split, boxplot

I want to produce seasonal boxplots for a lot of different time series. I hope that the code below clearly illustrates what I want to do.

My question is now, how to do this in the most elegant way with as few lines of code as possible. I can create an new object for each month with the function "subset" and then plot it, but this seems to be not very elegant. I tried to use the "split" function, but I don't know, how to proceed from there.

Please tell me if my question is not clearly stated or edit it to make it clearer.

Any direct help or linkage to other websites/posts is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Here is the code:

```
## Create Data
Time <- seq(as.Date("2003/8/6"), as.Date("2011/8/5"), by = "2 weeks")
data <- rnorm(209, mean = 15, sd = 1)
DF <- data.frame(Time = Time, Data = data)
DF[,3] <- as.numeric(format(DF$Time, "%m"))
colnames(DF)[3] <- "Month"

## Create subsets
Jan <- subset(DF, Month == 1)
Feb <- subset(DF, Month == 2)
Mar <- subset(DF, Month == 3)
Apr <- subset(DF, Month == 4)

## Create boxplot
months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")
boxplot(Jan$Data, Feb$Data, Mar$Data, Apr$Data, ylab = "Data", xlab = "Months", names = months)

## Try with "split" function
DF.split <- split(DF, DF$Month)
head(DF.split)
```

Comment: Thanks to both ROLO and James for the fast response and the great solution.

Comment: The code is not working under Win 7 and R 2.14.1. Some of the monthly values ("%b") got an NA, and are therefore omitted during plotting. Any ideas why that happens, @James ? I had similiar problems with time functions under Windows before. The code is working fine under Mac OS X, though!

Comment: The behaviour of `%b` depends on the current locale, essentially trying to match month abbreviations in the local language; locale behaviour in turn tends to be extremely platform-dependent, I suspect that even the same nominal locale can act differently on different platforms (or you may have different locales set on the different machines).  It won't be as elegant, but you may be able to create a solution with `month.abb` (hard-coded English month abbreviations) instead of `strftime(...)`

Comment: Now, it works again on the Windows machine. I changed the Sys.setlocale to Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English") and this works fine. Thanks to @Ben Bolker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are better off picking out the month names directly with the `"%b"` format and using an ordered factor and the formula interface for `boxplot`:

```
DF$month <- factor(strftime(DF$Time,"%b"),levels=month.abb)
boxplot(Data~month,DF)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using 'ggplot2' (and @James' month names, thanks!):

```
DF$month <- factor(strftime(DF$Time,"%b"),levels=month.abb)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=,month, y=Data)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image: boxplot]

(BTW: note that in 'ggplot2' "*The upper and lower "hinges" correspond to the first and third quartiles (the 25th and 7th percentiles). This differs slightly from the method used by the boxplot function, and may be apparent with small samples.*" - see [documentation](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/docs/geom_boxplot.html))

Answer (score 0):

To set months as ordered factor **in any locale settings** use a trick which can be found in help page for `?month.abb`:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "German_Germany")
DF$month <- factor(format(DF$Time, "%b"), levels=format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%b"))
```

And you could plot it in `lattice` as well:

```
require(lattice)
bwplot(Data~month, DF, pch="|") # set pch to nice line instead of point
```

[image: Lattice boxplot]