# Subset boxplots by date, order x-axis by month

Tags: r, date, boxplot

I have a year's worth of data spanning two calendar years. I want to plot boxplots for those data subset by month.

The plots will always be ordered alphabetically (if I use month names) or numerically (if I use month numbers). Neither suits my purpose.

In the example below, I want the months on the x-axis to start at June (2013) and end in May (2014).

```
date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-06-01"), as.Date("2014-05-31"), "days")

set.seed(100)
x <- as.integer(abs(rnorm(365))*1000)

df <- data.frame(date, x)

boxplot(df$x ~ months(df$date), outline = FALSE)
```

I could probably generate a vector of the months in the order I need (e.g. `months <- months(seq.Date(as.Date("2013-06-01"), as.Date("2014-05-31"), "month"))`)

Is there a more elegant way to do this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
boxplot(df$x ~ reorder(format(df$date,'%b %y'),df$date), outline = FALSE)
```

I am using `reorder` to reorder your data according to dates. I am also formatting dates to skip day part since it is you aggregate your boxplot by month.

[image]

#### Edit :

If you want to skip year part ( but why ? personally I find this a little bit confusing):

```
boxplot(df$x ~ reorder(format(df$date,'%B'),df$date), outline = FALSE)
```

[image]

#### EDIT2 a ggplot2 solution:

Since you are in marketing field and you are learning `ggplot2` :)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y=x,
                   x=reorder(format(df$date,'%B'),df$date),
                   fill=format(df$date,'%Y'))) +
  xlab('Month') + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Year")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to order the plot January to December. This seems to be a common cause of vexation for people, here is my solution:

```
date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-06-01"), as.Date("2014-05-31"), "days")

set.seed(100)
x <- as.integer(abs(rnorm(365))*1000)

months <- month.name
boxplot(x~as.POSIXlt(date)$mon,names=months, outline = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052305/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-split-data-and-produce-seasonal-boxplots) - use a factor, not a date:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- as.integer(abs(rnorm(365))*1000)

df <- data.frame(date, x)

# create an ordered factor
m <- months(seq.Date(as.Date("2013-06-01"), as.Date("2014-05-31"), "month"))
df$months <- factor(months(df$date), levels = m)

# plot x axis as ordered
boxplot(df$x ~ df$months, outline = FALSE)
```

[image: plot ordered]